# Crear documento con datos que puedan ser rellenados desde Java

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Javafx y en este tengo un registro de clientes. En cada registro introducido hay la posibilidad de imprimir un documento relacionado con este, en el que tendré que rellenar ciertos datos automáticamente (nombre, dirección...) y enviarlo a la impresora. Por tanto, necesito crear una plantilla del documento y desde Java pasarle los datos necesarios.

Lo más parecido que he hecho nunca es crear reportes utilizando Jasperreports, pero tampoco tengo mucha experiencia en ello. Con mi poca experiencia he descartado esta posibilidad ya que el documento no es un listado de datos.

He pensado que alomejor utilizando pdf o word podria hacerlo. He encontrado algo sobre pdf llamado fdf que me ha parecido un poco lo que yo buscaba pero no estoy segura y tampoco he encontrado ninguna explicación ni ningún ejemplo donde se haga lo que yo quiero hacer. También me ha parecido que en word se pueden crear fields o variables que después puedo sustituir desde Java con el valor real. Pero buscando en google tampoco he encontrado nada que me ayude a ver como se hace.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo y de qué herramienta tengo que utilizar para ello?

Comment: Estás interesado en que el programa lo imprima automaticamente o solo quieres crear un documento y luego imprimirlo manualmente?

Comment: Quiza [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) te pueda servir

Comment: Sin duda tu mejor opción es JasperReports. Para hacer una plantilla solo te bastará un par de tutoriales en YouTube y una hora. Además, JasperReports tiene su propio editor basado en Eclipse que es fácil de manejar.

Comment: @Mayuso Que lo imprima automáticamente seguro. Si después está la posibilidad de poder guardarlo y que lo imprima el usuario cuando quiera tampoco estaría de más. Pero en principio el programa debería enviarlo a la impresora automaticamente

Comment: @MitsuGami Pero he probado Jasperreports y lo he visto más para, por ejemplo, sacar un listado con todos los clientes. Pero lo que necesito es más como un formulario con datos del cliente rellenados automáticamente  y con algún párrafo de texto. Y lo he intentado pero me ha parecido muy difícil de reproducir con jasperreports.... No sé, a ver si no encuentro otra solución volveré a intentarlo pero no me ha parecido para este caso la herramienta más adecuada (como digo tampoco tengo una gran experiencia con jasperreports)

Comment: Puedes usar también [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). No es tan "fácil" de entrar en contacto, pero te permite justamente lo que quieres: formularios.

Comment: Nosotros utilizábamos Jasper Reports para generar facturas de clientes. Jasper puede ejecutar queries y recibir parámetros, y depende de ti cómo quieras que luzca el reporte. También puedes optar por crear el PDF a mano mediante iText, quizás crear un archivo Excel o Word mediante librerías como Aspose o Apache POI, entre otros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno...finalmente he conseguido hacerlo utilizando el openoffice y pasándolo a pdf...
He creado mi plantilla con el openoffice y desde este se pueden añadir campos de formulario y ponerles un nombre. Openoffice te permite exportar el documento a pdf incluyendo los formularios que tenga. Una vez lo tengo en pdf, utilizo PDFBox desde Java para leerlo y puedo ir obteniendo los campos del formulario mediante el nombre que les he puesto y asignarles un valor. Según vi, también puede servir itext para hacer esto. Con PDFBox el código ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument;
    try {
        pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(rutaPDF);

        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

        rellenarCampo(acroForm, "nombre", "Pepito Perez");
        rellenarCampo(acroForm, "calle", "C/ Grande");

        pdfDocument.save(rutaFinalDocPDF);
        pdfDocument.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void rellenarCampo(PDAcroForm acroForm, String nombreCampo, String valor) throws IOException{
    PDField field = acroForm.getField(nombreCampo);
    if( field != null ) {
        field.setValue(valor);
    }
    else {
        System.err.println( "No se ha encontrado el campo "+nombreCampo+"!");
    }
}
```

Para imprimir el documento he utilizado el código que me han proporcionado @jasilva y @Mayuso

Answer (score 0):

Ok por lo que comentas al final, si puede ser muy complicado reproducirlo en jasper report

Este es un ejemplo en iText de como construir un PDF con campos rellenables

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-8

O podrias hacer un archivo RTF se que habrira en Word , para que lo rellene el usuario, exportandolo de la siguiente forma:

```
Document document = new Document();

File file = new File(path+ ".rtf");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
RtfWriter  writer=RtfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
```

La principal desventaja contra Jasper Reports es que no tiene diseñador y toca hacerlo todo en codigo

Esto seria la estructura  para generar un documento

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Font chapterFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC);
    Font paragraphFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL);
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("This is the title", chapterFont);
    Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chunk), 1);
    chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
    chapter.add(new Paragraph("This is the paragraph", paragraphFont));
    document.add(chapter);
    document.close();
```

---

Ahora para la impresión podria ser de la siguiente forma

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, null, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = getPrintService().createPrintJob();
printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
fis.close();


PrintService getPrintService(){


    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
    PrintService[] pservices =
                 PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
    if (pservices.length > 0) {
       return pservices[0];

    }
    else return null;// o quiza lanza excepcion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

public class PdfFiller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Ruta del archivo PDF de la plantilla
            String templatePath = "ruta/de/la/plantilla.pdf";
            
            // Objeto PdfReader para leer la plantilla
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);

            // Objeto PdfStamper para escribir en el PDF
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("ruta/del/pdf/resultante.pdf"));

            // Obtener los campos de formulario del PDF
            AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();

            // Agregar datos a los campos de formulario
            fields.setField("nombre", "Juan");
            fields.setField("apellido", "Pérez");
            fields.setField("email", "juan.perez@example.com");

            // Cerrar el PdfStamper y el PdfReader
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
            
            System.out.println("¡Plantilla PDF cargada y datos agregados exitosamente!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).